# How do you say "no" if you don't want to continue co-op in freeplay?

Tags: bloons-td-5

I played co-op a few times. There is an option if you want to continue playing in free play mode as well. I can see a "Yes" button but there is no "no". How do reject the offer?

Comment: Reject kinda seems harsh :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't technically say "No". You can just go back to the main menu and start another game.

There is no option to start a new map or anything either. You would have to create a separate new game.